# How to align image and text divs side by side in section tag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need these two divs , the text and the image to be side by side despite the screensize. I want them to be equal distance of each other.

The divs are aligned side by side just fine. the issue is when I go to desktop, the distance increases, how do i stop that?

```css
#welcome {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center'
    align-items: center;
   }
  
  
  
  .flex-child:first-child {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="welcome" className="flex">
    <div className="welcome-text">
      <h2 className="mainTitle">Nutrition Integrated<br /><span>Data.</span><span>Insight.</span><span>Integrated.</span></h2>
      <p className="welcome-para">Get access to our huge range of credit and debit cards that allows you to send unlimited transactions without getting charged any fees!.</p>
      <button>Free Demo</button>
      <button>Sign Up    </button>
    </div>
    <div className="welcome-img">
      <img src={SI} alt="SI"></img>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the problem here? how much you want them to have distance from eachother? can you give mroe info of what you exactly need? they should be next to each other with the code written.

Comment: it doesnt matter the distance, I just want to know how to keep the ditance the same throughout all screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox for that:

```css
#welcome {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: /*center | space-between | space-around*/;
 align-items: center;
}
```

And by the way you made .welcome-text { flex: 1 }. Remove that. It will make the .welcome-text to take all the available space!

Comment: hi, thanks, ive edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the distance same at all screen sizes, you can do this:

```
   #welcome {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   }
  
  .welcome-text {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
```

They will have the distant same as `40px` in all screen sizes.

Comment: do i still add the ` .flex-child:first-child {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }`

Comment: no need for that, try the code above. it should work. if not send a screenshot of it.

Comment: doesnt work , ive added screenshots on the question

Answer (score 0):

found the asnwer using grids:

```js
 .grids {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
 .grids-3 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
```